# add value to java 2 dimensional dynamic arrays

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

how can I possibly add a value to a 2 dimensional dynamic arrays?

```
String emp[][] = {
{"001","Superman","Manda","123-1233","02-14-1970","Male","Manager","20,000","Regular"},
{"002","Batman","Manda","33-1233","07-14-2007","Male","Clerk","20,000","Regular"},
};
```

I try this code

```
int arrLen = emp.lenght;
emp[arrLen][0] = "003"
emp[arrLen][1] = "Superwoman"
emp[arrLen][2] = "QC"
emp[arrLen][3] = "123-1233"
emp[arrLen][4] = "03-12-2012"
emp[arrLen][5] = "Female"
emp[arrLen][6] = "Supervisor"
emp[arrLen][7] = "10,000"
emp[arrLen][8] = "Regular"
```

but it doesnt work

can anyone help me?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java arrays have fixed length. If you want resizable array use [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Example:

```
ArrayList<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
list.add(new String[]{"Superman","Manda","..."});
list.add(new String[]{"Superwoman","Manda","..."});
```

Comment: There isn't, but you can use ArrayList<ArrayList<Person>> - you can do the nesting without needing a nested type

Comment: No, but if number of columns is fixed you can use `ArrayList` of arrays: `ArrayList<String[]>`.

Answer (score 4):

You can't *add* to an array - after creation, the size is fixed. You should consider using a [`List<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) implementation such as [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)... ideally having created a type to encapsulate this information better than just an array of strings. It looks like you've got dates, names, numeric values etc in there - why not *use* that information?

For example:

```
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
people.add(new Person(1, "Superman", "Manda", new TelephoneNumber("123-1233"),
           new LocalDate(1970, 14, 2), Gender.MALE,
           "Manager", 20000, SalaryType.REGULAR);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo

```
lenght
```

Also, statements have to end in

```
;
```

Finally, what your actual problem is: the length of an array is fixed at creation; array[array.length] will always point outside the array.

Answer (score 0):

The array.length returns a number that is 1 higher than your index.

Answer (score 0):

Array objects are of fixed size. You can allocate a new, larger `String[][]` object and move the subarrays over to it -- i.e.,

```
String[][] tmp = new String[emp.length + 1][];
for (int i=0; i<emp.length; ++i)
   tmp[i] = emp[i];
emp = tmp;
```

After this, there's an empty spot at the end of your main array. Fill it with

```
emp[emp.length-1] = new String[] {"003", ...};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two big issues with your current code.

1) Arrays aren't dynamic, and have fixed size. You should instead use the ArrayLists data structure, where you can add values.

2) Your array.Length returns some length n, but your array is indexed from 0 to (n-1). Hence, referencing to the length, will give you an index out of bounds exception.